# deploy wordpress to bitbucket

Tags: wordpress, bitbucket

I should need a automatic backup for my wordpress sites.

I thought about bitbucket but is it possible to automate a deploy to my website from wordpress to bitbucket every N minutes/hours?

I have been looking for a while and I only found a plugin that deploy from bitbucket to wordpress, the opposite of my need.

I can't use an extension of plesk because my plesk is v12 and git extension need v17.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

While I understand your requirement, I should advise not to do that since any git server is not really meant to be used as a content backup service. Ideally, WP Backups contain uploads, images, videos, PDFs and other binary files. Bitbucket (git) is a source control service.

There are several WP Backup plugins and services that are way better than using GIT as a backup service, I recommend looking for those options.

Now, what you want is still possible if you have access to the server OS (Linux?). You could set a **[cronjob](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux)** (a scheduled task) that runs the desired **git** command, ie: `git add . && git commit -m "Backup" && git push`.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: thank you, for our suggestion, i'll try now!
i don't understand about the first paragraph, what is the problem to store code, image and other to bitbucket?

Comment: ehm i'm a very noob, can i have a entire git command?
thank you (this is embarrassing)

Comment: Glad that it helped! It's not that it can't be used to store code and files, but the most ideal use of bitbucket is to version your code, you can include the assets of your project too of course, but if you're WP is changing frequently (posts, file uploads, etc) then a better fit it's a WP backups service that should also backup your database, offer you one-click restores and more.

Also, keep in mind that BitBucket allows a max of 1GB per repo (free tier) and we know that WP installs can grow a lot.

You can try the cronjob strategy and see how it goes :) good luck!

Comment: I recommend taking a look at GIT documentation, you only need the basics: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push. However I already added the whole git command in the answer. The sequence is: Add, Commit, Push.

Comment: my db have a server's backup services, so i haven't problem for this. i don't know about limit 1 gb thank you for the advice. i would try to deploy just for code, but i don't know the correct command in cron job (i'm a noob about git/bitbucket) i create a new repository and i don't know what i need to do, can you help me please?

Comment: @AndreaG.Pigliafreddo it seems you need to get more info about how to setup git, while I can't give you the exact answer I can guide you in the process: Create a repo > Initialize your wp directory as a git repo (google git init), point it to the repo you created, then try to manually execute the git command I gave you from your git-initialized wordpress directory (just to see if it works); then try to setup the cronjob. Good luck!

Comment: the problem is that git doen't work, i try to create a git help command in plesk in cronjob and the services it fails

Comment: @AndreaG.Pigliafreddo I think your server may not have git installed (?)